# Just turned on icloud for phone, but moved contacts from Outlook on local machine

Tags: iphone, icloud, ms-office

Hi and thanks in advance for any help provided! I just upgraded my phone to a 6s and turned on iCloud. That moved all my contacts from phone and Outlook on local machine to the cloud.  I would like to maintain contacts and calendars locally. How to I bring items back out of the cloud?
Jim

Answer (score 2):

Open the Settings app of your iPhone, and scroll down to iCloud. There, switch off the slider at "Contacts". After a warning message, the contacts will be deleted from your cloud and are stored only locally on your device again. You can then start to sync your contacts with outlook again, probably by using iTunes.

Comment: It's important to remember, @jim, that doing this will stop iCloud syncing for your contacts and calendar.